# why my login authentication is not working ? this code is neither redirecting me anywhere nor showing me any error

Tags: python, django

```
def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password1'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('../')

        else:
            return render(request,'login.html',{'error':'username or password is wrong'})

    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')
```

Comment: Check your `login.html` template. Perhaps you aren't doing a `POST` request, or you aren't displaying `{{ error }}` anyway correctly. Note that Django comes with a [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) - why not use this instead of writing your own?

Comment: Where are your forms? You have not passed any forms to be rendered in the template. Pass the login form in the template and print the errors using `{% for error in form.errors %} {{ error }} {% endfor %}` in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your login form that is to be passed to the template.

For example:

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Your Email/Username', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Your Password', max_length=100)
```

Then in your views.py, you can define a view function as:

**views.py**

```
from .forms import LoginForm
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid:
            user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password1'])
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request,user)
                return redirect('../')
            else:
                return render(request,'login.html',{'form': form, 'error':'username or password is wrong'})
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request,'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Then in your template, you can render the form as:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }} <--render the form in other ways as preferred-->
{% for error in form.errors %} //for displaying the fields where errors have occured
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use django inbuilt loginview:-

in urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns =[
path('login/' , LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html') , name ='login') 
 ]
```

in ur login.html

```
  <h1> login page!! </h1>
   <form method='POST'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type='submit' value='Login'>
   </form>
```